# Expired Community URL redirects to login page silently without error message

Tags: community, error-messages, url, login

In my instance of SF, when a new community user gets created, an email is sent out to the user with a login link (community_url). If the link isn't clicked on within next 7 days, the link is set to expire.

The challenge is that in some cases, users click on that link after it has expired and are then silently redirected to the community login page. In most cases users aren't sure of what to do next and keeps clicking on the Forgot Password link. However, since their account wasn't setup properly in the first place (login > change password etc.), this step fails and they're stuck in this loop forever - leading to very bad customer experience.

What can I do to ensure that when they click on expired link, they're shown an error message about the expired link with further instructions?

Thank you.

Comment: What can you do - write custom code that takes over the whole sequence and you'll have your own, desired UX.

Comment: Hi @identigral. Of course that is an option (and probably the best way to go about it). Can you please point me to.skme.resources to override this process via custom code?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_password_management.htm&type=5 is a start

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - but I wouldn't be here popping the question unless I had checked out help.salesforce.com first.